# ReactiveX Observable to trigger when I want to

Tags: observable, reactivex

I try to trigger an Observable like as a click as well an interval. How can I trigger?

I tried obs.retry(), but it does nothing.

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.obs = this.http.get('http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1');
    obs.subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response.text());
    })
    setInterval(() => {
        console.log('update');
        this.obs.retry();
    }, 1000)
}

onClick() {
   console.log('click');
   this.obs.retry();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to resubscribe when you want to "retry".

When you construct an observable, like when you do `this.http.get(...)` you are just defining what you will want to do with data. So you are saying "I want to get the data from the server, then filter out the data I don't want (`.filter(...)`) and map it to my object definition so I can use it (`.map(...)`)", but not making any of those actions just yet.

When you `.subscribe()` to that observable, you are running all these operations you just defined. So in this case, you should do something like:

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.obs = this.http.get('http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1');

    setInterval(() => {
        console.log('update');
        this.loadPosts();
    }, 1000)
}

loadPosts() {
    this.obs.subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response.text());
    });
}

onClick() {
    console.log('click');
    this.loadPosts();
}
```

If you understand this part, then you can look into making this a full Rx solution:

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
    let httpStream = this.http.get('http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1');
    this.clickSubject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);

    this.obs = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
        .merge(this.clickSubject)
        .flatMap(() => httpStream);

    // Note that is not a good practice to have subscribe in constructors, should have this in init() method or something similar.
    this.obs.subscribe(() => {
        console.log(response.text());
    });
}

onClick() {
    console.log('click');
    this.clickSubject.onNext();
}
```

Here I'm setting up a stream that ticks every second (`Rx.Observable.interval`), join that stream with one that yields every time there's a click (`this.clickSubject`) and maping each tick for a new result of the `httpStream`.

Comment: thanks so much, still learning, but thanks so much, it will takes some times to master, because i am working learning so much with ng2 / material2 plus this. i saved it so much!! CIAO!

Comment: If you think this answer solved your problem, you can put the green tick on it, marking it as the accepted answer (I get more reputation if you do haha)